# Python: monitor subprocess output with glib?

Tags: python, subprocess, stdout, glib

So far I have gotten away with using the following method for capturing and processing the output of a subprocess:

```
    process = subprocess.Popen(<some-command>, shell=True, stderr = subprocess.PIPE)

    while True: 
        output = str(process.stderr.readline())
        if process.poll() is not None:
            break
        if output:
            if '<some-output>' in output:
                print('<something>')
            elif'<some-other-output>'in output:
                print('something-else')
```

however, I now need to monitor the output in the background while the program is doing something else.
This program is build around Glib Mainloop.

I tried to add this to the Glib Idle, but that doesn't seem to work.

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The I/O operations in Python's standard library do not integrate well with GLib's main loop and I/O operations. In this case I would recommend using `GLib.Subprocess` instead of the Python module.